# How to make Brie En Croute less rich/cheesy?

Tags: baking, cheese, puff-pastry, brie

I prepared Brie En Croute using 1/2 of a 16.9oz/480g round of Brie and a single layer of frozen puff pastry dough. I also added a few dollops of apricot preserves inside. When wrapped, the pastry mostly just had one layer of dough but some was double-layered.

After baking, the pastry was beautiful but was too rich and creamy. I have had Brie En Croute before and the sweetness of the preserves, richness of the cheese, and savory pastry flavor were balanced well. This however, was definitely just CHEESE.

#### question

How can I make Brie En Croute but balance the flavors better? How do I make the cheese less... cheesy?

#### In the future...

[I will definitely cut off the rind a bit!](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/3054/71420) It was very pungent in the Brie En Croute.

Comment: Hello, and welcome. In the future, maybe wait a bit before accepting an answer. This will encourage other responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use younger Brie.

You can get Brie in various ages, all the way from barely a week old - which is clean & white all the way through, & almost dry & crumbly, mild as cream cheese [Philadelphia etc]; right up to a year or more - dark yellow & pretty much a gooey liquid with a slightly more solid centre.

Obviously, the older/more ripe, the stronger the flavour.